# How to access video frames from external process?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

Windows 32 bit application memory limit is around 2gb approximately.
I need to play 4 to 8 HD video files or live camera graphs. Which is not possible by a single 32 bit application.
So I would like to play each graph in separate 32 bit application and access those video frames from my main application. In this case I could manage my need.

Could some experts give me some clue to do this if c++ ?

Is there any ready solution to achieve this ?

gaamaa

Comment: You could try running FFmpeg as a process and set its output file as `-` then this send output data back to your program as bytes via `stdout` (instead of saving to disk).

Comment: Thanks VC.One,  Parsing the stdout as video stream would be another task. We need direct video atream. Eg streaming raw UDP:// and receiving that UDP:// from my mail app. without latency.

Comment: Have you tried ffmpeg C API --> https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html

Comment: Thanks Vencat, not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It is no ready solutions like you need as I know. Stdout, output to files and another stuffs are not applicable for huge video frames.

I suggest using ffmpeg libraries with shared memory as frame buffer for AVFrame. You may implement it by yourself, it is not so complicated. Don't allocate and free shared memory buffers for every frame, it will cause a bottleneck. You need to allocate shared memory pool for all frames once on start processing and reuse them during decoding/encoding process.

Also you will need to implement IPC mechanism at least for decoders synchronization, you can use same shared memory + global system mutex.

BTW, all that techniques may help you, but will not solve task with 8 HD files in realtime. You need to use GPU codecs (in FFMPEG they named nvenc/nvdec), in that case you can use GPU memory instead RAM.